# Textarea lines to array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php variable that contain value of textarea as below.

```
Name:Jay
Email:jayviru@demo.com
Contact:9876541230
```

Now I want this lines to in array as below.

```
Array
(
[Name] =>Jay
[Email] =>jayviru@demo.com
[Contact] =>9876541230
)
```

I tried below,but won't worked:-

```
$test=explode("<br />", $text); 
print_r($test);
```

Comment: You can split() the string to separate by \n\r (jumb line) and : to prop/value

Comment: I have try this

Comment: $test=explode("<br />", $text);
print_r($test); but each line become an key value but i want as mention in question.

Comment: `<br/>` tag is html line break .it will not consider as new line php server side .

Comment: refer to this url https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/convert-multi-line-colon-separated-value-list-to-array-key-value-pairs/92316

Comment: why don't you create separate input field for each one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this code using php built in `PHP_EOL` but there is little problem about array index so i am fixed it

```
<?php
$text = 'Name:Jay
Email:jayviru@demo.com
Contact:9876541230';
$array_data = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);

$final_data = array();
foreach ($array_data as $data){
    $format_data = explode(':',$data);
    $final_data[trim($format_data[0])] = trim($format_data[1]);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_data);
```

and output is :

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Jay
    [Email] => jayviru@demo.com
    [Contact] => 9876541230
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but see my question.I want array as given i question

Comment: ShafiqulIslam  and @Sanj you both have to take care of extra spaces if some-one added accidently in text-area. You array indexes and value both have spaces then (if you are using above answer)

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam  i have solution of that in my answer.If you want to check

Answer (score 5):

***Easiest way to do :-***

```
$textarea_array = array_map('trim',explode("\n", $textarea_value)); // to remove extra spaces from each value of array
print_r($textarea_array);

$final_array = array();
foreach($textarea_array as $textarea_arr){
    $exploded_array = explode(':',$textarea_arr);
    $final_array[trim($exploded_array[0])] = trim($exploded_array[1]);

}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/846556

Answer (score 0):

This also works for me.

```
$convert_to_array = explode('<br/>', $my_string); 
for($i=0; $i < count($convert_to_array ); $i++)
{ 
$key_value = explode(':', $convert_to_array [$i]); 
$end_array[$key_value [0]] = $key_value [1];
} 
print_r($end_array); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need create 3 input:text, and parse them, because if you write down this value in text area can make a mistake, when write key. Otherwise split a string into an array, and after create new array where key will be odd value and the values will be even values old array